# How to count the numbers of elements in parts of a text file using a loop in Perl?

Tags: perl, text-files

I´m looking for a way to create a script in Perl to count the elements in my text file and do it in parts. For example, my text file has this form:

```
ID                       Position   Potential  Jury agreement NGlyc result
(PART 1)
NP_073551.1_HCoV229Egp2   23 NTSY   0.5990     (8/9)           +     
NP_073551.1_HCoV229Egp2   62 NTSS   0.7076     (9/9)           ++        
NP_073551.1_HCoV229Egp2  171 NTTI   0.5743     (5/9)           +     
...
(PART 2)
QJY77946.1_NA             20 NGTN   0.7514     (9/9)           +++   
QJY77946.1_NA             23 NTSH   0.5368     (5/9)           +     
QJY77946.1_NA             51 NFSF   0.7120     (9/9)           ++    
QJY77946.1_NA             62 NTSS   0.6947     (9/9)           ++  
...
(PART 3)
QJY77954.1_NA             20 NGTN   0.7694     (9/9)           +++   
QJY77954.1_NA             23 NTSH   0.5398     (5/9)           +     
QJY77954.1_NA             51 NFSF   0.7121     (9/9)           ++      
...
(PART N°...)
```

Like you can see the ID is the same in each part (one for PART 1, other to PART 2 and then...). The changes only can see in the columns Position//Potential//Jury agreement//NGlyc result Then, my main goal is to count the line with Potential 0,7 >=.

With this in mind, I´m looking for output like this:

```
Part 1: 
1 (one value 0.7 >=)
Part 2: 
2 (two values 0.7 >=)
Part 3: 
2 (two values 0.7 >=)
Part N°:
X numbers of values 0.7 >=
```

This output tells me the **number of positive values** (0.7 >=) for each ID.

The pseudocode I believe would be something like this:

```
foreach ID in LIST
    foreach LINE in FILE
        if (ID is in LINE)
           ... count the line ...
    end foreach LINE
end foreach ID
```

I´m looking for any suggestion (for a package or script idea) or comment to create a better script.

Thanks! Best!

Comment: In part one, there are two lines that are less than 0.7. Is that a mistake in your expected output, or did you write that wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote that wrong. My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the number of lines, for each part, that match some condition on a certain column, you can just loop over the lines, skip the header, parse the part number, and use an array to count the number of lines matching for each part.

After this you can just loop over the counts recorded in the array and print them out in your specific format.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $part = 0;
my @cnt_part;
while(my $line = <STDIN>) {
    if($. == 1) {
        next;
    }elsif($line =~ m{^\(PART (\d+)\)}) {
        $part = $1;
    }else {
        my @cols = split(m{\s+},$line);
        if(@cols == 6) {
            my $potential = $cols[3];
            if(0.7 <= $potential) {
                $cnt_part[$part]++;
            };
        };
    };
};

for(my $i=1;$i<=$#cnt_part;$i++){
    print "Part $i:\n";
    print "$cnt_part[$i] (values 0.7 <=)\n";
};
```

To run it, just pipe the entire file through the Perl script:

```
cat in.txt | perl count.pl
```

and you get an output like this:

```
Part 1:
1 (values 0.7 <=)
Part 2:
2 (values 0.7 <=)
Part 3:
2 (values 0.7 <=)
```

If you want to also display the counts into words, you can use [`Lingua::EN::Numbers`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Numbers) (see [this program](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/blob/master/so-67118077/count2.pl) ) and you get an output very similar to the one in your post:

```
Part 1:
1 (one values 0.7 <=)
Part 2:
2 (two values 0.7 <=)
Part 3:
2 (two values 0.7 <=)
```

All the code in this post is also [available here](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/tree/master/so-67118077).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your script. I gonna try it!

Comment: Hi again! Sorry for the delay. I ran the script with a test file but the output is empty. Could you tell me what means this: <STDIN> and $cnt_part? @wsdookadr

Comment: Could you explain to me the previous question please? @wsdookadr

Comment: Did you run the script like this: `cat in.txt | perl count.pl` ?

Comment: Yes, for example, I tried in my windows system (never stop) and in Linux using `cat in.txt | perl count.pl` (result in an empty output). If I sent you a file like a tried with your script, could you try it if works in your system?

Comment: Sure, upload the file somewhere and give a link

Comment: https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_NetNGlyc/blob/main/Output_NetNGlyc Here is the output example, please let me know if you can see the example file. @wsdookadr

Comment: I can see it. Your `(PART N)` lines are missing in it. The format of the file differs from your original message here on SO.

Comment: I try to represent the "PART N" like the "ID" (for example YP_003858584.1). I wrote PART 1 to simplify the example because the "ID" is diverse. Do you think if is there a form to represent this?

Comment: PART N is only a form to represent the different sections of my input file. Do you understand me?

Comment: Yup, got you. Hold on a few minutes while I make some adjustments.

Comment: Thank you man! I really appreciate your help !!

Comment: Try [this program](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/blob/master/so-67118077/count3.pl) instead for your new file format.

Comment: Thank! Works it! 
`PART ADK66841.1_NA:
18 (values 0.7 >=)
PART YP_003858584.1_BtCoVBM48_gp2:
18 (values 0.7 >=) ` However, I think that the count is not completely correct, because in both parts (ID) there are 9 values with 7>=, for some reason the output did something like this: 9 + 9 (18). Anyway, thank you I gonna try to fix the last part